# Macro expansion ignores some tokens in MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, macros

I have some problems with macro expansion in msvc compiler.
I expect the following code to be expanded to `F x`, which it does on gcc and clang.
But msvc expands it to just `F` ignoring `x` token. What's going on here?

```cpp
#define S(s) s
#define F()

#define M() S(S(F) x)

M() // expands to 'F' on msvc
```

However, without defining `F()` it expands to `F x` on msvc too, as expected.

```cpp
#define S(s) s
// #define F()

#define M() S(S(F) x)

M() // expands to 'F x' on msvc
```

I'm using Compiler Explorer site to check this code. Compiler version is x64 msvc v19.latest.

Comment: You probably should specify your exact preprocessor/compiler version.

Comment: I'm using compiler explorer x86 msvc v19.latest

Comment: Save yourself a lot of trouble and stop using macros. Plain functions are perfectly fine.

Comment: @КирилловДмитрий to add additional information [edit] your question please, instead of responding in comments.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I'm using macros only for tetsing purposes. Rest of the code is macro-free.

Comment: You never defined `F`, only `F()`. Fix either one of those issues.

Comment: @Blindy I know. This code was never meant to be compiled into some meaningful code.

Comment: It wasn't a question of whether you know or not, I'm telling you that's the problem. Macros aren't overloadable magic boxes, they're C constructs, and the preprocessor chokes and dies on the expansion of `F`. Either remove `F()`, or call it, not F.

Comment: @Blindy Why it tries to expand F? I thought compiler will try to expand function-like macro only if it's followed by parentheses.

Comment: If you are using Compiler Explorer, please save your code on Compiler Explorer and include the link in your question, since it allows anyone to see the same thing you are seeing.

Comment: @Blindy there is nothing wrong with defining F() and then writing F

Comment: @user253751 Thank you for pointing out this Compiler Explorer feature. I will use it in future questions.

Comment: Your problem is this: **S(`S(F) x`)**. You're sending S() an *undefined* operation. What does `(Y x)` mean? (Where `Y = S(F)`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`/Zc:preprocessor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/preprocessor-experimental-overview?view=msvc-170) to switch to the new, standard-conformant preprocessor. It behaves as you expect.