# Which tokens are ignored by MSVC pre-processor in expanding macros?

Tags: c, visual-studio, macros, c-preprocessor

I saw [Macro expansion ignores some tokens in MSVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72534881/macro-expansion-ignores-some-tokens-in-msvc) earlier, and was curious about the behaviour of the MSVC preprocessor. Obviously the correct answer to that and similar questions is "Don't use the MSVC preprocessor, use the newer, conforming one instead", but out of curiosity I tried to figure out what exactly is going on.

I tried [playing around with the preprocessor on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/5P3jzdPTa), and my working theory is something like "If MSVC considers expanding a function-like macro inside an argument list to another function, and decides not to do the expansion, it replaces the argument list with the name of the function-like macro it decided not to expand".

Excusing the informal language above, this idea seems to hold pretty well for single-argument macros, as we see in the above Godbolt link, but doesn't seem to work too well for two-argument macros, which seem to be doing something a little differently.

Code I was playing around with included below:

```
#define S(s) s
#define Z(a, b) a b
#define F() 

#define K() S(x S(F) x)
#define L() S(x S(F))
#define M() S(S(F) x)
#define N2() S(F) x
#define N() S(N2())
#define O() S(S(S) x)
#define P() S(S(A) x)
#define R() Z(Z(F,F) x, Z(Z,Z) y)
#define Q() Z(Z(Z,Z) x, Z(F,F) y)


K() // expands to 'F'
L() // expands to 'x F'
M() // expands to 'F'
N() // expands to 'F x'
O() // expands to 'S x'
P() // expands to 'A x'
R() // expands to 'F F'
Q() // expands to 'Z Z x F'
```

[On GCC, we get the following (different) output](https://godbolt.org/z/4q9dPG1sK):

```
x F x
x F
F x
F x
S x
A x
F F x Z Z y
Z Z x F F y
```

I've looked at the [documentation for the MSVC preprocessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/preprocessor-experimental-overview?view=msvc-170), and was not able to find an answer.

So, my question is, under what circumstances does the above behaviour (erasing some tokens from the argument list) happen, and which tokens will be erased?

Note: This question is *not* "the MSVC preprocessor is not doing what I want", but rather "the MSCV preprocessor behaves differently than the GCC one, I would like to know the rules it follows".

Comment: Your example is too complicated and contorted, but I'm sure the compiler does the rights thing, and read my comment on your other question.

Comment: @not2qubit the other question is not mine.

Comment: @not2qubit, the MSVC preprocessor does not agree with the one used by GCC or Clang. So the only way they can both be right is if there's some ambiguity in the spec, or there is some undefined behavior in my examples. In which case pointing out what is going on would be a reasonable answer to this question as well

Comment: The MSVC compiler is a very different beast than GCC. There are not just a few differences, there are probably hundreds. There is no reason at all that the MSVC should behave the same as GCC. In fact it has many compiler pre-processor directives, not available on GCC, and vice versa. (E.g. `#warning` on GCC, not available on MSVC.)

Comment: @not2qubit The reason MSVC should behave the same as GCC is because the behaviour of the preprocessor is described in the C standard. It's not unreasonable to expect two C compilers to both implement the C standard correctly.

Comment: Incompatible extensions are one thing, having a "broken" preprocessor (i.e. one that doesn't behave as described in the C standard.) is an entirely different matter. I'm not asking for every difference between MSVC and GCC, I'm asking for details on a very specific piece of MSVC that doesn't implement the standard correctly

Comment: Define *broken*. It's just a matter of opinion, often based on being comfy with the old GCC. MSVC/VS is trying to simplify and consolidate things as much as possible. Getting rid of weird siht and legacy functions that are really not useful, and just being of fringe use. Can you give me one useful example where you actually need to do what you are asking for?